# Session expiration issue in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat

I have deployed my application (Struts2, spring, hibernate) in a clustered environment. I am using Tomcat 7 for our deployments.

I have configured session timeout to 60 minutes in web.xml in my application.

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Issue:

Session gets expire exactly after 1 hour though the session is active (I am still working with the application). It happens only once the browser creates new session (JSESSIONID). If I login into the application again, the session expires only after clicking logout (or) after idle time (60 mins). When the browser shares same JSESSIONID to the server after login (JSESSIONID from previous session) this issue doesn't occur.

Comment: _Session gets expire exactly after 1 hour though the session is active_ elaborate it

Comment: Jigar Joshi, I have edit my issue. Please re-check.

Comment: "When the browser shares same JSESSIONID to the server after login (JSESSIONID from previous session) this issue doesn't occur." Can you give more detail about this too? You must be doing something unusual for this chain of events to occur surely?